# Duplicating an array using .NETMF

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, .net-micro-framework

**How would I be able to repeat the array multiple times using .netmf (VB or C#)?**

Below you'll find the function I used to build a Byte(). All it does is get an 8 char string (Ex.10101000) and phases each char replacing a 1 with 252 and 0 with 128 and dumps it to an array of bytes. Ex.

```
Dim bytes() as array = {252,128,252,128,252,128,128,128}
```

^^^^  Would be the equivalent.^^^^

So  say I use my function and I pass it a string of 10101011

```
Dim N as integer = 3
Dim Teststring as string = "10101011"
Dim testbyte() as byte = Allbytes2send(Teststring , N)
```

Testbyte() should now be filled with the phase string 3 times

```
For each b in Testbyte
Debug.Print(b.tostring)
Next
'{252,128,252,128,252,128,252,252,252,128,252,128,252,128,252,252,252,128,252,128,252,128,252,252}
```

---

Function

```
 Shared Function Allbytes2send(ByVal color As String) As Byte()



    Dim bitcolor As String() = New String(color.Length - 1) {}

    Dim b2sa As Byte() = New Byte(bitcolor.Length - 1) {}

    For i As Integer = 0 To color.Length - 1
        bitcolor(i) = color(i).ToString()
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To bitcolor.Length - 1
        Dim data As String = bitcolor(i)
        Select Case data
            Case "0"
                bitcolor(i) = "128"
            Case "1"
                bitcolor(i) = "252"
        End Select
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To bitcolor.Length - 1
        b2sa(i) = Byte.Parse(bitcolor(i))
    Next




    Return b2sa
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out I wrapped it in another function. By using Array.copy and reassigning my byte array I was able to dynamically change the size of array and copy using predetermine number multiplied by any given number.

```
  Shared Function SendAllLeds(ByVal LedsData As Byte(), ByVal LedCount As Integer) As Byte()

    Dim testbyte2() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim y, z As Integer


    y = (24 * LedCount) - 1
    z = 0

    ReDim testbyte2(y)

    While z <= y
        Array.Copy(LedsData, 0, testbyte2, z, 24)
        z += 24
    End While

    Return testbyte2


End Function
```